# MySQL Update - how to delay the update?

Tags: mysql

How can I delay the update on each row in a table?

For instance I have 10 rows and if I run this:

```
UPDATE article SET created_on=unix_timestamp(now()), updated_on=unix_timestamp(now());
```

These 10 rows will have the same timestamp. How can I have different timestamp on each row by looping and delaying the update?

Any ideas?

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article` (
  `article_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'page, post',
  `url` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `content` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `backdated_on` INT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The manual datetime that is modified or input by the user.',
  `created_on` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'The permanent datetime when the article is created.',
  `updated_on` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'The datetime when the article is updated on.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `url_UNIQUE` (`url` ASC))
ENGINE = MyISAM
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COMMENT = 'Entity that holds the article with one-to-one properties.'
INSERT_METHOD = NO
KEY_BLOCK_SIZE = 1;
```

Comment: Use a session variable that you increment, add the value of auto_increment to the timestamp, create a procedure that performs the first suggestion for you.. as you can see, there are many ideas but the only relevant question hasn't been asked - **WHY**? This smells like XY problem to me.

Comment: Yeah, solve this alleged problem another way. I see no problem with exact same timestamps. In fact, they are fun. They can confirm a grouping later for forensics. If you need some other incrementor, then create one. If you already have an auto_increment, you can ask us for a strategy for another. If you don't have an autoinc column, add one. If you don't know what an autoinc is, just ask.

Comment: also, publish the output from running `create show table article`

Comment: @Drew thanks for the comment. so what is an 'autoin'?

Comment: and `auto_increment` is a column (int, bigint) that auto increments by 1 (normally) as you insert rows. It is great for sequencing. Seems you are concerned with sequencing based on your delayed TS thing !

Comment: @Drew I updated my question to add my article schema.

Comment: I use auto increment for article IDs.

Comment: Please join me in [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290) chat so I can understand more. This thread gets long.